# Inserting default-listitem into dropdown before executing stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to insert a listitem in the first row of a dropdown menu and then execute a storedprocedure. I've tried using insert(), additem() and more without any luck.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `AppendDataBoundItems` property of the drop down to the `true` and then you can insert/append your item before or after binding to data from database

Comment: Thank you! No wonder items.insert(); didn't work without this one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "All"));

You can use it after or before excuting stored procedure.It will insert "All" as a first list item of dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response! Where would be the ideal place to insert it? On load or right before I execute the sp?

Comment: I do the .DataBind first (bind results)......then I do the Insert (at posistion 0).  Toe-may-toes, toe-maut-toes.......but that's what I do.  I also define the value as a CONST ... at the top of my page...to avoid a bunch of loose-goosey "--All--" or "--Select--" strings all the the place.